# Как проверить, установлено ли местоположение

Tags: java, android, gps

как узнать задано ли местоположение по GPS, т.е, когда приложение ищет GPS то это поиск, а как узнать в своем приложении найдены ли спутники?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способа узнать статус по спутникам.

Первый. Этот способ используется только в старых приложениях и сейчас deprecated, то есть его не рекомендуется использовать.

```
GpsStatus.Listener lGPS = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        GpsStatus status = lm.getGpsStatus(null); 
        if( status!=null){
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = status.getSatellites();
            Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
            int i=0;
            while (sat.hasNext()) { // цикл для работы с отдельными спутниками
                  GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
                  count++; //тут количество спутников
            }
        }
    }
};
        locManager.addGpsStatusListener(lGPS);
```

Второй способ, который рекомендует гугл.

```
gnssStatusCallBack = new GnssStatus.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSatelliteStatusChanged(GnssStatus status) {
                    super.onSatelliteStatusChanged(status);
                    satelliteCount = status.getSatelliteCount();// к примеру  можно получить количество спутников
            }
        };
        locManager.registerGnssStatusCallback(gnssStatusCallBack);
```

Comment: заинтересовал первый способ, не могли подсказать, что он возвращает, и как его вовсе использовать ? второй способ по проще но он только с API 26+

Comment: Добавил первый способ. Идеально их комбинировать. Проверять версию андроида и использовать способ в зависимости от версии

Comment: это возвращает 0 спутников, gps то пойман.

Comment: Он может быть пойман. Но это не значит, что вы получите координаты, когда у вас ноль спутников. Попробуйте получить координаты

Comment: Стоит программа GPS Test, 18 спутников видит, к 5 подключена, координаты получаю, но код что выше, возвращает 1 (извините за ошибку выше, код возаращет не 0 а 1) а спутников то 5.